# WORDPRESS: Cannot upload images as a normal user via https

Tags: wordpress, file-upload

Using standard Wordpress uploader I can upload images as an admin without any problems, but when I logging in with another user role (subscriber for ex), uploading does not work. And it does not work only via https protocol, I have temporarily disabled redirect in .htaccess file and found this fact. "HTTP ERROR"  or "Error during uploading" (my translation, I am using localised WP) message occured and uploading breaks. I have tried inspecting with Chrome developer console, and when I am uploading image the following error displays " https://example.com/wp-admin%2Fasync-upload.php&reauth=1" Also, after this unsuccessful attempt to upload user gets kicked to login screen and have to login again. None of discribed above is affecting admin user.
What I have already try to fix this:

1. Disabling plugins
2. Changing theme
3. Changing hosting including localhost
4. Checking hardcoded http links
5. Checking and changing user permissions
6. Google
7. Various functions and other things

But nothing helps. I am in desperate. Seems it is all about https protocol. Please, can someone tell how to fix this?

Comment: Can you check your PHP errorlog to see exactly what error is happening? As you mentioned the async-upload.php script only outputs "PHP" error in the console.

Comment: Sorry my bad, there was other messages I messed up: "HTTP ERROR" or "Error during uploading" (my translation, I am using localised WP) I have edited the first post. And a was checking error logs and cannot found anything, some few minor notices and that is all.

Comment: Can you login as a "Contributor" or "Editor" user and check if the problem also happens there as well over HTTPS?